# Very strange behaviour in Promise - Uncaught (in promise) - v8 bug?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, v8, gecko

Different notation of the same expression - not the same behaviour?

1. This will toss `Uncaught (in promise) v8` for you,

and I think it shouldn't! You may refresh on [mdn://Promise/catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) and [гост://ecma2015](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise.prototype.catch).

```js
var a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(_ => reject('v8'), 0));
a.catch(a => 1);
a.finally(a => 1);
```

2. Basically the same code, but works as expected.

```js
var a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(_ => reject('v8'), 0))
  .catch(a => 1);
a.finally(a => 1);
```

**!!** There must be at least one `.finally` or `.then` chained, else example #1 will not toss that `Uncaught (in promise)`.

Reproduced in the latest versions of *FF* and *Chromium* (though I did not test this with [servo](https://servo.org/) yet).

- `.catch` callback is executed in example #1.
- `.setTimeout, 0` just to position `reject` to top of call stack, timeout could be more than 0 anyways.

Can someone please explain, what did I miss? Is it just me or JavaScript?

Comment: Doesn't look like a bug to me.  #1 and #2 assign different values to a.

Comment: In #2 you're assigning the result of `.catch()` to `a`, not the original promise.

Comment: I object! `new Promise(() => {}).catch(_=>1) instanceof Promise // true` and `new Promise(() => {}) instanceof Promise // true`. Did you also try both snippets without a `finally` block?

Comment: @user2263572 @Barmar in specification link it states `.catch()` will return `this`. Or maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: In the first example, you are using Promise **branching**, which will give different results from Promise **chaining**

Comment: Thank you @blex, so when I do branching, it still the same confusion I get: `var a = new Promise((a,r) => r('v8'), 1000);
a.catch(a => 1); //a is rejected promise, NO ERROR` and `var a = new Promise((a,r) => r('v8'), 1000);
a.catch(a => 1);
a.then(a => 1); // existence of this gives ERROR` I will dig a bit about keywords you shared thanx!